# Get postgresql exact log file name with sql

Tags: postgresql, logs

I get current log file by using SQL without getting in server via ssh. So I use a query like the one below;

```
SELECT pg_read_binary_file(
  concat_ws('/', 
    current_setting('log_directory'),
    'postgresql-Fri.log'
  )
);
```

Log files are not too big so i am fine with that. The thing is, I cannot use this query in a generic way. Is there a way to get 'postgresql-Fri.log' from my `log_filename` setting which is currently `postgresql-%a.log` but the format can differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a [`pg_current_logfile()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-info.html) function returning this information:

> Primary log file name, or log in the requested format, currently in
>   use by the logging collector.

but it's a new feature of PostgreSQL 10, which you probably don't run since it hasn't yet got out as a `General Availability` release (it's still `Release Candidate` at the moment).

With previous versions, you're pretty much on your own to figure out the current name, either by interpreting `log_filename`, or by finding the latest modified, for instance with a combination of `pg_ls_dir` and `pg_stat_file`:

```
SELECT file, -- should be the latest logfile
  (pg_stat_file(current_setting('log_directory')||'/'||file)).modification
  FROM  pg_ls_dir(current_setting('log_directory')||'/') as list(file)
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

This can fail if the server's clock goes backward or if non-log files are dumped into the same directory as the log files.